# Setting a div background image Opacity

Tags: css

I was trying to set the opacity of a image which is the background image of the div. When I used opacity=0.5, then it says "opacity is not known to CSS".

```
    <div style="background-image:url('../Images/MainBackground.jpg'); 
        opacity=0.5" class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

Then I changed the code from the sitemaster page to a seperate css file as shown below.

```
.main
{
     background-image: url('../Images/MainBackground.jpg');    
     height: 100%;
     opacity=0.5;
     padding: 0px 12px;
     margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
     min-height: 420px;   
}
```

here also it says opacity is not known to css.

I want to set the opacity of div's background image to 0.5. Any help ?

I am using VS 2010 (C# 4.0)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer is technically correct, in your case you want the opacity of the *background* not the entire `.main` container. You cannot set the background image opacity without affecting the child elements of the page. If you have a white background, you can create a child element that has a width and height of 100% with an opaque white background that will contain the data inside.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="opaque">
        // your content here
    </div>
</div>
```

And the styles with rgba color "white" and 0.5 opacity

```
<style>
    .main {
        background-image: url('../Images/MainBackground.jpg')
    }

    .opaque {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried with this. But not working as expected.